# What is the correct way to fit a gaussian mixture model to single feature data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, reshape, mixture-model

`data` is a one dimensional array of data.

```
data = [0.0, 7000.0, 0.0, 7000.0, -400.0, 0.0, 7000.0, -400.0, -7400.0, 7000.0, -400.0, -7000.0, -7000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -7000.0, 7000.0, 7000.0, 7000.0, 0.0, -7000.0, 6600.0, -7400.0, -400.0, 6600.0, -400.0, -400.0, 6600.0, 6600.0, 6600.0, 7000.0, 6600.0, -7000.0, 0.0, 0.0, -7000.0, -7400.0, 6600.0, -400.0, 7000.0, -7000.0, -7000.0, 0.0, 0.0, -400.0, -7000.0, -7000.0, 7000.0, 7000.0, 0.0, -7000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6600.0, 6600.0, 6600.0, -7400.0, -400.0, -2000.0, -7000.0, -400.0, -7400.0, 7000.0, 0.0, -7000.0, -7000.0, 0.0, -400.0, -7400.0, -7400.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -400.0, -400.0, -400.0, -400.0, 6600.0, 0.0, -400.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -400.0, -400.0, 0.0, 0.0, -400.0, -400.0, 0.0, -400.0, 0.0, -400.0]
```

I would like to fit some gaussians to this data and plot them.

If I run

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import mixture

x = np.array(data)
clf = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=2, covariance_type='full')
clf.fit(x)
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: Expected n_samples >= n_components but got n_components = 2, n_samples = 1
```

and

```
DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Ok... I can live with this. The warning tells me what to do. However, if I run

```
x = np.array(data).reshape(-1,1)
clf = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=2, covariance_type='full')
clf.fit(x)
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: Expected the input data X have 1 features, but got 32000 features
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the right way?

**Edit:**

I just realized that I misread the error message. Not `fit()` is rainsing the error, but `score_samples()`.

I am trying to plot the gaussians afterwards.

```
x = np.linspace(-8000,8000,32000)
y = clf.score_samples(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

So `x` seems to be the problem. However, neither `x.reshape(-1,1)` helps, nore `x.reshape(1,-1)`.

Comment: have you tried to reshape it the other way (1, -1)?

Comment: Yes, I already tried this. See my comment to  John Moutafis answer.

Comment: I am not getting any error when reshaping as (-1,1), on scikit 0.18

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the error myself. As I stated in my edit, not `fit()` was raising the error, but `score_samples()`.

Both functions excpect a multi-dimensional array.

Working code:

```
data = np.array(data).reshape(-1,1)
clf = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=1, covariance_type='full')
clf.fit(data)

x = np.array(np.linspace(-8000,8000,32000)).reshape(-1,1)
y = clf.score_samples(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have many samples of just one feature, try

```
your_samples_list = map(lambda x:[x], your_samples_list)
```

this will convert it into a list of lists

```
[a,b,c] -> [[a],[b],[c]]
```